# Using asymptotic expansion $B_{n} = a- 1 + O(n^{-2})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-explanation, asymptotics

Let
$$
\lambda_{n} = \frac{n\pi}{L} - \frac{L}{2n\pi(a-1)}
$$
such that $n^{2} > \frac{L^{2}}{2\pi^{2}(a-1)}$, $L > 0$ and $ 1 \neq a$ and $a > 0$.

My question: If
$$
B_{n} = \frac{L^{2}}{(n^{2}\pi^{2} - L^{2}\lambda_{n}^{2})}
$$
then using asymptotic expansion, we get
$$
B_{n} = a- 1 + O(n^{-2})
$$
Why? What does $O(n^{-2})$ mean?

I think:
$$
\lambda_{n}^{2} = \bigg(\frac{n\pi}{L} - \frac{L}{2n\pi(a-1)} \bigg)^{2}= \bigg(\frac{2n^{2}\pi^{2}(a-1) - L^{2}}{2n\pi L(a-1)} \bigg)^{2} 
$$
This is,
$$
\lambda_{n}^{2}  = \dfrac{(2n^{2}\pi^{2}(a-1))^{2} - 4n^{2}\pi^{2}(a-1)L^{2} + (L^{2})^{2}}{(2n\pi (a-1))^{2}L^{2}}
$$
Then, we have
$$
n^{2}\pi^{2} - L^{2}\lambda_{n}^{2} =  \dfrac{(2n\pi (a-1))^{2}n^{2}\pi^{2} - (2n^{2}\pi^{2}(a-1))^{2} + 4n^{2}\pi^{2}(a-1)L^{2} - (L^{2})^{2}}{(2n\pi (a-1))^{2}}
$$
Therefore, we get
$$
B_{n} = \dfrac{(2n\pi (a-1))^{2}L^{2}}{(2n\pi (a-1))^{2}n^{2}\pi^{2} - (2n^{2}\pi^{2}(a-1))^{2} + 4n^{2}\pi^{2}(a-1)L^{2} - (L^{2})^{2}}.
$$
Unfortunately, I can't continue. Help me, please.

Comment: $O(n^{-2})$ means any sequence an such that $|b_n|≤Cn^{-2}$ with some constant $C$
 and $n$ large enough.

Comment: You need to try another way.

Comment: @JhonMec And why don't you speak the right? Comments that I need to try otherwise, I don't know. :(